# I can't achieve a specific result, a problem in grouping data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with creating sql query, I will present my problem in the picture

[image]

The photo above shows my prepared CTE table, what I want to achieve is table posted belove

[image]

Explanation
1. Column **Group** - If the value of the Type field is equal to T then we should set the next value starting from 1 to the next repetition of the value of T in the Type column
2. Column **MaxGroupValueToPoint** - Returns the largest value in the group it is in but we check from where the cursor is to the beginning of the group (sort by field id_ex asc)

CTE tabel contain 7+ million records

My problem is that I dont know how to achieve that group column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doable with windowed functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT *,grp=SUM(CASE WHEN [Type]='T'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARITITON BY id ORDER BY id_ex)
 FROM tab
)
SELECT *, MaxGroupValueToPoint = MAX(Score) OVER(PARTITION BY id, grp ORDER BY id_ex)
FROM tab
ORDER BY id_ex;
```

How it works:

- conditional SUM to create group, tick-tock mechanism, every 'T' adds 1
- windowed MAX to grab highest value per group

Comment: "If you specify an ORDER BY but not a frame extent, the default is used, which is RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW."
Now i know why your query works.